# Localising Localizable.string in xcode 5 breaks the whole file

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

Whenever i try to localise my Localizable.strings file it seems to break and Xcode won't use it anymore.

I start by creating a new single view application. By default the applications is set up to use Base Localization and english is already set up as the main language.
In my ViewController.m i add the following code to the viewDidLoad method

```
    NSString *text = NSLocalizedString(@"someKey", @"some comment");
    NSLog(@"%@", text);
```

When i run the application it logs "someKey" because there is no "Localizable.strings" file.
I then create the Localizable.strings file and add the following to the file:

```
    "someKey" = "Some value";
```

When i run the application again it logs out "Some value", just as expected.

I want my app to also be in norwegian so i add the language to the list of localisations.

[image: Localizations where Norwegian has been added]

I chafe the language of the iOS simulator to norwegian and run the app again. Since i haven't localized "Localizable.strings" yet, the app still logs "Some value".

I then click on "Localizable.strings" and click on the "Localize" button in the utilities pane. I select "English" as the language and click "localise". The file has not been localised to english, but to "Base". I run the app and it still logs "Some value".

Next i add Norwegian localisation. The file now has to "subfiles", one for base and one for norwegian. I change the "someKey" value to be "Norwegian" and "Base".

Now, when i run the app, it stills logs out "Some value" even though that text is not present in the app anymore. I can reset the iOS simulator, clean and restart Xcode, but still my app logs out "Some value".

I have no idea what is going on! Anyone?

Comment: What do you mean > 'I change the "someKey" value to be "Norwegian" and "Base".'? That doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 0):

1, check if all quote signs " are paired in your local.strings file
2, clean (command+shift+k) and run

App will use default language strings if the specified language string is not found.